# Where to place javascript directly related to a view helper (Zend Framework 1)

Tags: php, zend-framework, model-view-controller

I am new to Zend Framework 1 and have been working on my first project. While creating a pretty detailed view helper, I realized there is a bit of javascript (mainly ajax calls and such) that are directly related to the view helper. Currently I just have them defined in the view script that calls that helper, but I plan to move it now that I have it working correctly.

My question:
Where is the recommended place to put javascript that is directly related to a view helper?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better late than never. 
You should put your javascript code into the view file of the helper.

Basically if your helper is located somewhere like :

```
/views/helpers/YourHelper.php
```

You can render it in it's own view with :

```
return $this->view->render('-helpers/your-helper.phtml');
```

And put the javascript code into the helper view located at :

```
/views/scripts/-helpers/your-helper.phtml
```

Hope this will help.
Best

Comment: Thanks Samy, this was what I ended up doing and it seems to be most appropriate. Appreciate the response.